# INT(3) column not cliping the value to appropriate length and allowing the full value to be inserted - MySQL

Tags: mysql, int, unsigned

I have an INT(3) UNSIGNED column. If I insert a value with character length more that 3, it doesn't clip that value but inserts it.

Whats happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FROM [What does "size" in int(size) of MySQL mean?](http://alexander.kirk.at/2007/08/24/what-does-size-in-intsize-of-mysql-mean/)

> Finally, let's come to the place of the manual where there is the
>   biggest hint to what the number means:
>
> Several of the data type descriptions use these conventions:
>
> M indicates the maximum display width for integer types. For
>   floating-point and fixed-point types, M is the total number of digits
>   that can be stored. For string types, M is the maximum length. The
>   maximum allowable value of M depends on the data type.
>
> It's about the display width. The weird thing is, though2, that, for
>   example, if you have a value of 5 digits in a field with a display
>   width of 4 digits, the display width will not cut a digits off.
>
> If the value has less digits than the display width, nothing happens
>   either. So it seems like the display doesn't have any effect in real
>   life.
>
> Now2 ZEROFILL comes into play. It is a neat feature that pads values
>   that are (here it comes) less than the specified display width with
>   zeros, so that you will always receive a value of the specified
>   length. This is for example useful for invoice ids.
>
> So, concluding: The size is neither bits nor bytes. It's just the
>   display width, that is used when the field has ZEROFILL specified.

```
mysql> create table a ( a tinyint );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.29 sec)
mysql> show columns from a;
+-------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| a | tinyint(4) | YES | | NULL | |
+-------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
1 row in set (0.26 sec)

mysql> alter table a change a a tinyint(1);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.09 sec)
Records: 0 Duplicates: 0 Warnings: 0

mysql> insert into a values (100);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from a;
+-----+
| a |
+-----+
| 100 |
+-----+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


2 Some code to better explain what I described so clumsily.
mysql> create table b ( b int (4));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.25 sec)

mysql> insert into b values (10000);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from b;
+-------+
| b |
+-------+
| 10000 |
+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> alter table b change b b int(11);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 1 Duplicates: 0 Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from b;
+-------+
| b |
+-------+
| 10000 |
+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> alter table b change b b int(11) zerofill;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 1 Duplicates: 0 Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from b;
+-------------+
| b |
+-------------+
| 00000010000 |
+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> alter table b change b b int(4) zerofill;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.08 sec)
Records: 1 Duplicates: 0 Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from b;
+-------+
| b |
+-------+
| 10000 |
+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> alter table b change b b int(6) zerofill;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 1 Duplicates: 0 Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from b;
+--------+
| b |
+--------+
| 010000 |
+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 2):

actually `3` there is a *display width* which works for `ZEROFILL` that pads zero on the right. It doesn't limit the capacity of the integer as it stores upto `4294967295` starting from zero.

example,

```
CREATE TABLE tableName
(
    x INT(3) ZEROFILL NOT NULL, 
    y INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO tableName (x,y) VALUES
(1, 1),
(12, 12);

SELECT x, y FROM tableName;
```

Result:

```
  x          y
001          1
012         12
```

Using  `display width` has no effect on how the data is stored. It affects only how it is displayed.

- [Integer Types (Exact Value)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html)